# inline-grid vertical-align on second row's baseline

Tags: css

Is there a way in CSS to tell an inline-grid on which row's baseline it should vertically align? It seems to as if an inline-grid container with *vertical-align: baseline;* uses the first cell's baseline. But I'd like to use another cell's (or row's) baseline. Is this possible?

The code and image below shows what I have and what I want.

```css
.grid{
 display: inline-grid;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
 grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
 grid-gap: 20px;
 align-items: baseline;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 padding: 20px;
}
.grid>div{
 border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
  This is a line of Text
  
  <div class="grid">
   <div>A</div>
   <div style="font-size: 3em;">B</div>
   <div>C</div>
   <div>align me</div>
   <div style="font-size: 5em;">e</div>
   <div style="font-size: 3em;">f</div>
   <div style="font-size: 3em;">G</div>
   <div>H</div>
   <div>I</div>
  </div>
```

image showing vertical-alignment of inline-grid

[image]

**edit Jul 30**

So far I found out that when

1. grid's *align-items* is not *baseline* ,
2. the first cell spans two rows and has *height: 100%;* AND
3. the first cell contains an inline-block div with *height: 100%;* and *vertical-align: text-bottom;*

I can force the grid's baseline to be at the bottom of the second row, almost aligning my grid vertically as I wanted. Unfortunately, in my case the other cells in row two could be other than single-lined 1em high texts and then their shared baseline does not correspond to the baseline in cell 1 which defines the grid's vertical position.

So the question still remains: Is there a way to vertically align an inline-grid on the baseline of the second row?

Answer (score 0):

Brace yourself, this is not an April Fools' joke: I found an answer!

First, the working code:

```css
.grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "r . A B C"
    "r t D E F"
    ". . D E F"
    ". . G H I";
  grid-gap: 20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 20px;
  align-items: last baseline;
}
.grid::before {
  content: "\200b";
  grid-area: r;
  align-self: end;
}
.grid::after {
  content: "\200b";
  grid-area: t;
  align-self: baseline;
}
.grid>.grid-a { grid-area: A; }
.grid>.grid-b { grid-area: B; }
.grid>.grid-c { grid-area: C; }
.grid>.grid-d { grid-area: D; align-self: baseline; }
.grid>.grid-e { grid-area: E; align-self: baseline; }
.grid>.grid-f { grid-area: F; align-self: baseline; }
.grid>.grid-g { grid-area: G; }
.grid>.grid-h { grid-area: H; }
.grid>.grid-i { grid-area: I; }
```

```html
    This is a line of Text

    <div class="grid">
      <div class="grid-a">A</div>
      <div class="grid-b" style="font-size: 3em;">B</div>
      <div class="grid-c">C</div>
      <div class="grid-d">align me</div>
      <div class="grid-e" style="font-size: 5em;">e</div>
      <div class="grid-f" style="font-size: 3em;">f</div>
      <div class="grid-g" style="font-size: 3em;">G</div>
      <div class="grid-h">H</div>
      <div class="grid-i">I</div>
    </div>
```

Second, the explanation:

The use of `grid-template-areas` should help make it clearer:

- the first cell (area `r`) spans two rows and is `end` aligned, this makes its bottom edge align with the bottom edge of the second row
- the cells in the second row (`t`, `D`, `E`, and `F`) are `baseline` aligned
- the content in the first cell (`r`) and the second cell in the second row (`t`) are identical, this makes `r` and `t` align at their respective bottom edge which also happens to align their baselines (this one's crucial)
- cells for `D`, `E` and `F` span two rows, allowing them to grow downwards without affecting the bottom edge of `r` and `t`
- no cell in the first row must be `baseline` aligned for the whole grid to be aligned to the baseline of the second row. In my case, aligning them to `end` would do the trick, but I went with `last baseline` to demonstrate that FireFox is perfectly capable of showing the behaviour I hoped for

Third, the drawbacks:

- It depends on additional elements (pseudo-elements in my example), which can lead to styling issues when relying on grid gap
- Chrome doesn't know `last baseline` so the texts in elements outside row 2 are top aligned
- To me it's not clear whether FireFox ignoring the first row's baseline due to the use of `last baseline` is conform to the standard or just a happy accident. In case of latter, the initial question remains unanswered